# Jupyter lab installing/importing packages

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install `plotnine` for a notebook I am using. I have done the following:

1. Created a `conda` environment using python 3.6, and adding `plotnine`
2. Launching `jupyter lab` with the above environment activated
3. In the notebook, I added the following line:
   `!conda install -c conda-forge --yes plotnine`

However, my output makes no sense. First it says that all requested packages have been installed, and then it says it cannot find the module

```
!conda install -c conda-forge --yes plotnine
from plotnine import *

Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-386ef81e08ff> in <module>()
     11 get_ipython().system('conda install -c conda-forge --yes plotnine')
     12 ######
---> 13 from plotnine import *     # python clone of ggplot2
     14 matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 8]
     15 matplotlib.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2

ImportError: No module named 'plotnine'
```

In case there is a known conflict, here is the entire import statement:

```
import gsc # proprietary module
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets import interact, FloatSlider
from util_demo import *
# adding installation of plotnine, which is not included by default
# import sys
!conda install -c conda-forge --yes plotnine
######
from plotnine import *     # python clone of ggplot2
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 8]
matplotlib.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 24
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 24
matplotlib.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 24
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 24
```

---

**EDIT**: I also checked `sys.path` within the jupyter notebook and get the following. I do not  see anything about `conda` here. Should I update either `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH`?

```
['',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/adamg/.ipython']
```

Comment: Does running in different cells solve?

Comment: How should I separate them?

Comment: Just separating the plotnine import statement into a cell below does not work

Comment: OK! I don't know if this issue is related: https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/161 (it might?)

Comment: Did you install Jupyter Lab (or at least ipykernel) in the new environment, and make sure your notebook is using that kernel?

Comment: I just added the `jupyterlab` package (which includes ipykernel) to the environment, but that did not solve the issue. When I load jupyter lab I do not have the option to change the kernel to that environment. It only lists Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @DavideFiocco - The issue appears to be broader than just `plotnine`. I'm having a similar issue with `statsmodels`, for example.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. It looks like for me, my notebook in Jupyter Lab was running the base kernel and not the kernel of the virtual environment. Type

```py
import sys
sys.executable
```

into your notebook. For me, I got the result

```
'/anaconda3/bin/python'
```

instead of the desired

```
'/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python'
```

I solved it by following the instructions in the [iPython documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments). In summary, you need to install a new iPython kernel for your new environment. Run:

```sh
conda install -n myenv ipython
conda activate myenv
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```

Then, to run Jupyter Lab in the new environment:

```
conda activate myenv
jupyter lab
```

And you should be able to select the kernel "Python (myenv)" when you open a new notebook (also in the top right of an existing notebook).

Answer (score 1):

#try pip install first and rerun; the code line below should solve it:

**pip install plotnine**